# Writing into file in nodejs using fs.writefilesync

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am trying to write into a file using fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', originalNoteString) . When I run the program first time it is appending but when I run the program second time it is not appending again. Can Anyone help me what is happening here.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let orginalNote = {
    title: 'sometitle',
    body: 'somebody'
}

let originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(orginalNote);

fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', originalNoteString);

let noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes.json');

let note = JSON.parse(noteString);

console.log(typeof note);
console.log(note.title);
```

Comment: `writeFileSync` will overwrite file contents by default. For appending you should use `appendFileSync` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options

Comment: Thanks @BartoszGościński

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default mode of `fs.writeFileSync` is overwrite the complete file. As @Bartosz Gościński mentioned you can use `appendFileSync` or you set an [option](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) in `writeFileSync` to append the new text:

```
fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', originalNoteString, {flag: 'a'});
```

For more different flag values see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags)

Comment: What is `fileWriteSync`? Did you mean `writeFileSync`?

Comment: @Betty oh didn't see that. Thank you for pointing out :)